# Make 1 method async as well as sync in C#

Tags: c#, asynchronous, methods, task, synchronization

I have a very large set of methods that I want to make asynchronous accessible. The methods are complex and sometimes very long. The approach I can think off is copying all the existing methods and make them async. But when I have to make some changes I have to edit 2 methods. Is there a better approach with the code in one place?

As you can see the code is basically the same. ***Is it possible to combine those 2 methods into 1?***

```
    public async Task ManufacturersToWebshopAsync(HttpContext httpContext, ManufacturerNopServiceClient manufacturerNopServiceClient, bool onlyChanged = false, bool includeNight = false)
    {
        Log.Verbose("ManufacturersToWebshop", "Start", "");

        // client
        if (manufacturerNopServiceClient == null)
        {
            var host = httpContext.Request.Url.Host;
            manufacturerNopServiceClient = GetManufacturerNopServiceClient(host);
        }

        var manufacturers = _manufacturerService.GetAllManufacturers();

        if (onlyChanged && includeNight)
        {
            manufacturers = manufacturers.Where(x => x.State == State.Changed || x.State == State.Night).ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            if (onlyChanged)
            {
                manufacturers = manufacturers.Where(x => x.State == State.Changed).ToList();
            }

            if (includeNight)
            {
                manufacturers = manufacturers.Where(x => x.State == State.Night).ToList();
            }
        }

        var tasks = new List<Task>();
        var total = manufacturers.Count();
        var count = 1;

        foreach (var manufacturer in manufacturers)
        {
            Log.Information("ManufacturersToWebshop", "Manufacturer " + count + " van de " + total, "");
            //tasks.Add(ManufacturerToWebshop(httpContext, manufacturer, manufacturerNopServiceClient));
            await  ManufacturerToWebshopAsync(httpContext, manufacturer, manufacturerNopServiceClient);
            count++;
        }

        //await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

        Log.Verbose("ManufacturersToWebshop", "End", "");
    }
```

---

```
    public void ManufacturersToWebshop(HttpContext httpContext, ManufacturerNopServiceClient manufacturerNopServiceClient, bool onlyChanged = false, bool includeNight = false)
    {
        Log.Verbose("ManufacturersToWebshop", "Start", "");

        // client
        if (manufacturerNopServiceClient == null)
        {
            var host = httpContext.Request.Url.Host;
            manufacturerNopServiceClient = GetManufacturerNopServiceClient(host);
        }

        var manufacturers = _manufacturerService.GetAllManufacturers();

        if (onlyChanged && includeNight)
        {
            manufacturers = manufacturers.Where(x => x.State == State.Changed || x.State == State.Night).ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            if (onlyChanged)
            {
                manufacturers = manufacturers.Where(x => x.State == State.Changed).ToList();
            }

            if (includeNight)
            {
                manufacturers = manufacturers.Where(x => x.State == State.Night).ToList();
            }
        }

        var total = manufacturers.Count();
        var count = 1;

        foreach (var manufacturer in manufacturers)
        {
            Log.Information("ManufacturersToWebshop", "Manufacturer " + count + " van de " + total, "");
            ManufacturerToWebshop(httpContext, manufacturer, manufacturerNopServiceClient);
            count++;
        }

        Log.Verbose("ManufacturersToWebshop", "End", "");
    }
```

Comment: If you want us to help you, you need to post a small, yet complete re-produce of your problem. Asking a lengthy question without any practical example doesn't help.

Comment: Maybe you are able to just call your method from the async wrapper without making changes in this method

Comment: The right answer depends on what those methods are actually doing. In some cases, you might want to wrap a synchronous method with some `Task`. In other cases, you might want to wrap an asynchronous method with something that blocks until it's done. Even if your methods are all currently synchronous, that doesn't preclude the possibility that they would be better-implemented as asynchronous. And of course, the exact specifics of each of those options varies according to the exact nature of the work each method is doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to combine those 2 methods into 1?

Not in a good way that works in all scenarios. There are [hacks to write synchronous wrappers for asynchronous methods](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/04/13/10293638.aspx), and [other hacks to write asynchronous wrappers for synchronous methods](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/24/10287244.aspx) - but **none** of the options work in all scenarios. There is no generic, general-purpose solution for this problem.

I recommend that you consider what your method is doing, and decide whether it *should* be asynchronous or not. E.g., if it is doing I/O, then it should be asynchronous. Then, if the method should be asynchronous, just make it asynchronous (without a synchronous version).

If you're updating code, then this will require updating all the code that calls the new asynchronous method (and code that calls those methods, etc, etc). If this update will take too long to apply throughout the system, then (temporary) duplication of code is my recommended approach. However, if you don't control the calling code, then you might have to consider one of the hacks in the linked articles. Just be sure to think through the ramifications of each, and choose the one appropriate for your specific code.